# Does the Body Blows skill apply to more than hand-to-hand attacks?

Tags: dead-island-riptide

In Dead Island Riptide, John Morgan, the hand-to-hand combat specialist, has a skill in the third tier of the Combat tree called "BODY BLOWS".

"Gain chance to perform very powerful fist and kick attacks, with the ability to knock down your enemy.
1: Critical attack chance increased: 5%
2: Critical attack chance increased: 10%
3: Critical attack chance increased: 15%"

To borrow a saying, "text trumps table." So, I trust the second half, the numbers more than the implication in the description. However, this much of a critical attack chance increase applying to all attacks seems overpowered, so I doubt that it works with more than hand-to-hand attacks.

Note: John Morgan's attacks don't change, at least not in terms of animation and indubitable effect, with the acquisition of this skill.

Does the bonus apply to all types of attacks or just hand-to-hand ones?